# Poner equivalencias a una tabla temporal

Tags: sql-server

Trabajo con SQL Server 2008
Tengo la tabla #tmpEmpleado, el cual me da los resultado
Tengo una tabla Equivalencias donde se encuentra lo que dice como nombre

```
SELECT FirstName 
INTO #tmpEmpleado
FROM Employees

SELECT * FROM #tmpEmpleado
DROP TABLE #tmpEmpleado

DECLARE @Equivalencias TABLE(Nombre VARCHAR(100), NombreEquivalente VARCHAR(100))
INSERT into @equivalencias(Nombre, NombreEquivalente) VALUES('Andrew', 'Batman')
,('Steven', 'Superman')
```

En esta tabla #tmpEmpleado tengo los siguientes campos => `Nancy, Andrew, Janet, Steven`
Lo que espero es lo siguiente en la tabla principal
En la query que da el resultado Tengo a Andrew debe decir Batman, Steven debe decir Superman

El resultado me debe reflejar en el select de esta tabla #tmpEmpleado ¿debo de hacer un update a #tmpEmpleado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de lo que quieras obtener **(Select)** o tener **(Update)**.

```
Create table Employees (FirstName varchar(100));
Go
Insert into Employees(FirstName)
values
('Nancy'), 
('Andrew'), 
('Janet'), 
('Steven');
go
```

En el escenario que planteas, dado que no se ve el motivo para tener una tabla temporal, tampoco se puede saber si hay que cambiar los datos de ella.

```
SELECT FirstName 
INTO #tmpEmpleado
FROM Employees

DECLARE @Equivalencias TABLE(Nombre VARCHAR(100), NombreEquivalente VARCHAR(100))
INSERT into @equivalencias(Nombre, NombreEquivalente) VALUES('Andrew', 'Batman')
,('Steven', 'Superman')

Select * from #tmpEmpleado temp
    left join @Equivalencias equival on temp.FirstName = equival.Nombre;
```

[image: Resultado]

Si lo que necesitas es obtener el primer nombre, y en el caso de que tenga equivalente, ese.

```
SELECT FirstName 
INTO #tmpEmpleado
FROM Employees

DECLARE @Equivalencias TABLE(Nombre VARCHAR(100), NombreEquivalente VARCHAR(100))
INSERT into @equivalencias(Nombre, NombreEquivalente) VALUES('Andrew', 'Batman')
,('Steven', 'Superman')

Select coalesce(equiVal.NombreEquivalente, temp.FirstName) as FirstName
    from #tmpEmpleado temp
    left join @Equivalencias equival on temp.FirstName = equival.Nombre;
```

[image: Resultado 2]

Para el ejemplo no es necesario, tener una tabla temporal. Si fuera el caso.

```
SELECT FirstName 
INTO #tmpEmpleado
FROM Employees

DECLARE @Equivalencias TABLE(Nombre VARCHAR(100), NombreEquivalente VARCHAR(100))
INSERT into @equivalencias(Nombre, NombreEquivalente) VALUES('Andrew', 'Batman')
,('Steven', 'Superman')

Update temp set FirstName = coalesce(equiVal.NombreEquivalente, temp.FirstName) 
From 
    #tmpEmpleado temp
    left join @Equivalencias equival on temp.FirstName = equival.Nombre;

Select * from #tmpEmpleado;
```

[image: Resultado 3]

Comment: Voy pero el `SELECT` agregando un campo equivalencia pero si no tiene una equivalencia en vez de NULL que vaya el dato de la tabla `tmpEmpleado` si manejo una tabla temporal porque se maneja muchos datos es por eso que traigo solo una porción de datos que necesito

Comment: La ultima update, del ejemplo, ya utiliza el nombre del empleado, sino hay null. Y te muestro la select, para que veas que en la tabla #tempEmpleados, tienes lo que solicitas. Porque coalesce pone el nombre de la equivalencia, pero si es null, pone el nombre de la temporal.